# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1+5x^2)\arctan(x)^2}{x^{5/4}(1-x^2)^{1/4}} \text{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

This is an integral from a chat group:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1+5x^2)\arctan(x)^2}{x^{5/4}(1-x^2)^{1/4}}
\text{d}x
=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1 } }{4}\left(
\left ( \sqrt{2 }+1 \right )\pi^2+2\left ( \sqrt{2}-1  \right )
(8-3\ln(2))\pi-\frac{4\sqrt{2}\,\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2 }{\sqrt{\pi} }
\left ( 2\ln(2)+\left ( 2\sqrt{2}  -1\right ) \pi\right )    \right ).
$$
What I already know is that(integrating by parts)
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1+5x^2)\arctan(x)^2}{x^{5/4}(1-x^2)^{1/4}}
\text{d}x=8\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-x^2)^{3/4}\arctan(x)}{x^{1/4}(1+x^2)}
\text{d}x,
$$
but I don't know how to proceed. So any help would be highly appreciated.

---

(*June 5th,23*) Expanding $\arctan(x)/(1+x^2)$ into power series, denoting
$$
\mathscr{H}_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}
$$,
we have
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-x^2)^{3/4}\arctan(x)}{x^{1/4}(1+x^2)}
\text{d}x=\frac{3}{8}\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\mathscr{H}_n\,\Gamma\left ( n-\frac18 \right ) }{
\Gamma\left ( n+\frac{13}8 \right ) }.
$$

Comment: I rewrote the integral as $8\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(x-x^{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+t^{2}x^{2}\right)}dxdt$. It seems like the inside integral can be evaluated in terms of messy hypergeometric series, after experimenting with random values of $t$ between $0$ and $1$ and plugging them into WA (e.g. [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28x-x%5E%7B3%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B4%7D%7D%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2Bx%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%5Cleft%281%2Bt%5E%7B2%7Dx%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%7Ddx+where+t+%3D+1%2F2)).